# Symbolic reference to sub in a package, trying to understand

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Foo::Bar;
sub baz { print "$_[0]\n" }

package main;
{ # test 1
my $quux = "Foo::Bar::baz";
no strict 'refs';
&$quux(1);
}
{ # test 2
my $qux = 'Foo::Bar';
my $quux = "$qux\::baz";
no strict 'refs';
&$quux(2);
}
{ # test 3
my $qux = 'Foo::Bar';
my $quux = "$qux::baz";
no strict 'refs';
&$quux(3);
}
```

Output:

```
Name "qux::baz" used only once: possible typo at test31.pl line 21.
1
2
Use of uninitialized value $qux::baz in string at test31.pl line 21.
Undefined subroutine &main:: called at test31.pl line 23.
```

Why does `test 2` work, and why does backslash has to be placed exactly there?

Why does `test 3` not work, is it so far, in syntax, from `test 1`?

I tried to write that string as `"{$qux}::baz"`, but it doesn't work, too.

I came across this looking at source of `Image::Info` distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable name can either be simple like `$foo` or a fully qualified name (in the case of package variables). Such a fully qualified name looks like `$Foo::bar`. This is the “global” variable `$bar` in the package `Foo`.

If an interpolated variable is to be followed by a double colon `::` and the variable should not be interpreted as a fully qualified package variable name, then you can either:

- Use string concatenation: `$qux . "::baz"`
- Terminate the variable name with a backslash: `"$qux\::baz"`
- Surround the variable name (not the sigil) with curly braces, as if the name were a symbolic reference: `"${qux}::bar"`.

Comment: So, I'd say, interpolation is "greedy", it grabs as much as can possibly be interpolated (`$qux::baz`, here) and that fails, rather than it interpolates what it can (`$qux` to `Foo::Bar`, here) and appends the rest of the string to it.

Answer (score 3):

`$qux::baz` refers to scalar `baz` in package `qux`.

`"$qux::baz"` is the stringification of that scalar.

`"$qux::baz"` is another way of writing `$qux::baz.""`.

Curlies can be used to indicate where the variable ends.

`"$foo bar"` means `$foo." bar"`

`"${f}oo bar"` means `$f."oo bar"`

As such,

`"${qux}::baz"` is another way of writing `$qux."::baz"`.

`"$qux\::baz"` is a cute way of doing `$qux."::baz"` since `\` can't appear in variable names.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was first, but I think amon's explanation about "interpolated variable to be followed by a double colon" is more about what module's author intended to do and what confused me.